# Opening an URL in browser (may be chrome) in full screen

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser, android-browser

I am writing an android app in which I open an URL in the browser from inside the app. I want to open the url in browser in full screen by hiding the url entry bar. is it possible and if yes, how ca I achieve this? I do not want to use the webview to achieve this as I need to launch the URL in browser only.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

**Short:** *Opening the default browser or chrome in full screen is not possible.*

You can launch the default browser or any other browser with an URL, but you can't force it to be full screen.

Opening a default browser without forcing it to be full screen can be achieved using the following code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://google.com/"));
startActivity(i);
```

But I recommend to just use a WebView, I see no reason why you should not want to use it.
What you could do is create a custom (full screen) `Activity` with a `WebView` as layout. In the Activity you load the URL you wan't to show. This means you I'll need to add the internet permission to your manifest file since your app now requires internet.

Comment: he is aware of webview and he has already mentioned he don't want to use WEBVIEW

Comment: Well this is not possible, so he has no choice right?

Comment: Isn't there a way that from my activity that I use any html5 api which does this?

Comment: There is not really a long answer to this question the answer is just: No. How exactly are you programming your app? Android SDK or some other programming tool?

Comment: I am using android sdk and want to achieve this behaviour in some way from inside android activity where I get the URL entered by the user.

Comment: @RolfSmit : yupp as chrome is an external app so no other way. :P & thecommonGuy : to use HTML5 you again need to climb on webview :D